# Efficiently handling a large set of bit-mask flags

Tags: c++, c, computer-science

My function takes a filesystem path and a bit-mask describing the desired check to be performed on the FS object.

Does it Exist ?
Is it : File, Folder, SymLink ? Empty, Hidden ? Readable (R), Writable ?
Symlink : to a File, to a Folder ?

These 11 flags afford for a large number of combinations so I provide convenience flags like `SymLinkToAReadableFile` and such. This is not only convenient, it also spares some potential confusion : `SymLinkToFile | R` could mean a readable symlink (not very useful), the name "`SymLinkToAReadableFile`" leaves no doubt.

And to cut back on the required processing, I would define `RWHiddenFolder = Folder | R | W | Hidden`, and same for all things `Folder` related : `Folder | ..` , and likewise for `File` & `SymLink`.

This makes checking that user in not mixing `File` and `Folder` (which does not make sense) easy : `(flag & Folder) && (flag & File)` -> error.

But this makes `RWHiddenFolder | RWEmptyFile` same as `RWHiddenFile | RWEmptyFolder` same as `File | Folder | R | W | Empty | Hidden` :

- can't tell what the user actually passed !
- and thus can't build a precise error message
- if I make my function tolerant and ignore `SymLink` in presence of `Folder`, can't tell if user wants `Empty` or `Hidden` (or both) `Folder` !

The naive "solution" of affecting a bit to each possible combination obviously solves all of these issues, but builds a dense forest of `if/else` branches already for just making sure the provided flag combination makes sense, let alone doing the actual checks after that..

Is there a good trade-off between complex processing and convenient/clear interface (for the user) ?

Comment: You might be interested in Qt's [QFlag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qflags.html).

Comment: *`RWHiddenFolder | RWEmptyFile == RWHiddenFile | RWEmptyFolder == File | ...`*  Mixing bitwise operators with `==` comparison results is dodgy.  The results of any non-bitwise comparison like `==` will only be `0` or `1`.  It only works if you're checking "Are any of these true?"  It fails if you're trying to build a single value of bit flags, or if you use `&` instead of `|` and you're trying to check "Are *all* of these true?"

Comment: How large "bit field" variables are we talking about here, 32 bits? Look-up tables could be an option in some cases.

Comment: @Andrew : I only meant they are indistinguishable. IT guy reaction to IT shortcut-lingo, funny :) Question edited.

Comment: More than 100 (and could grow), the question actually presents a simplified version of the checks (there is also file size constraints, pattern matching - path ends with .csv ? - and number checking - positive ? Bigger than 20 ?..). Pre-computed table does solve the branch forest pb. of use input validation. Does not help distinguishing overlapping composite flags.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a reasonable solution (I had to !).
Sharing here for anyone with the same issue.

---

For those who prefer action to lectures (like me) : [sample](https://godbolt.org/z/zqx6jbYnc) (ignore the numerous constants definitions)

---

Obviously an `enum` can't do this, nor simple bitfields/sets : composing with `OR` loses the identity of the flag (`ReadableFile == Readable | File`).

But binary operations make for very effiecent (read "compact") manipulations (check, extract flag, ..)

So the idea is to carry `mask` and separate `id` :

```cpp
constexpr static auto nFlags = 96u; // total amount of flags

struct argFlag {
  string n; // reflection
  bitset<nFlags> id; 
  bitset<16> mask; // plain bitmask 
  
  // id == position of true bit
  argFlag(const string& s, const int i, const uint32_t m = 0 ) 
  : n(s), mask(m)   { id.set(i); } 

  // Cumulate id & mask bits, preserve reflection
  argFlag operator| (const argFlag& b)
  { argFlag r{ (n.empty()? ""s : n+" | ") + b.n, 0 }; 
    r.id = id | b.id; r.mask = mask | b.mask; return /* move */r; }
  
  // operator<< (has atom Id ? Meaning flag = .. | Atom | .. )
  bool operator<< (const argFlag& b)
  { .. }

}
```

Now you can make the list of base flags provided to the user, these are "atomic" flags : each one has 1 single `true` bit in `id`.

Now when user passes flag `Symlink2Folder | HiddenFile` :

- you can decompose it to its building atoms (2 here)  using `id`
- you can't confuse this with `Symlink2HiddenFolder | File` (same `mask`, but different `id` bits) : exact error messages are achievable.
- the `mask` member has all the right bits set (`Symlink | Folder | Hidden | File`). For cheap logical checks.

Reach for whatever member you need to achieve an operation on a flag (check id, check logical composition).

Using a couple of lambdas & macros, `validateFlags()` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/zqx6jbYnc)) can be very readably written in under 100 lines of code to handle gazillion unfathomable combinations (4 atoms make for 96x95x94x93 ~ 80 millions combinations).

You can try to get past `validateFlags()` in `main()` using whatever unlikely combination you can come up with ! Good luck `;-)`